# Sum of Digits / Digital Root codewars kata

Tags: javascript

Please, help me. I don't understand. Why second solution returns undefined?

```
function digital_root(n) {
  return n < 10 ? n : digital_root(n.toString().split('').map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
}
console.log(digital_root(12345678));
// expected output: 9

function digital_root(n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return n;
  } else {
    digital_root(n.toString().split('').map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
  }
}
console.log(digital_root(12345678));
// output: undefined
```

Comment: there is no return in the else

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your second code ignores the value you get returned from the recursive call. You should do something with it... `return` it.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return digital_root(n.toString().split('').map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
  }
}

console.log(digital_root(12345678));
```

Unrelated, but you can combine `split` and `map` by doing `Array.from`. Also the first version joins the two `return` statements with the conditional operator into a `return` of one expression:

```js
const digital_root = n => n < 10 ? n
       : digital_root(Array.from(n.toString(), Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b));

console.log(digital_root(12345678));
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?